# Extrapolation with exponential curve

Tags: regression, extrapolation

I would like to extrapolate time series using exponential curve while getting the parameters via linear regression.

Exponential curve is given as $g=e^{~a + b \cdot t}$. Since I want to use linear regression, I transformed it as $ln(g) = a + b \cdot t$.

My observations are (written as R vectors)

```
t <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
g <- c(1.038459504,1.019448815,1.017729187,1.010076583,1.00895011,1.007841198,+
       +1.006566597,1.009939696,1.003751382)
```

I omitted values for t = 1, 2 as they were way too different. It should be smooth.

---

Here comes my solution. I should probably regress $ln(g)$ against $t$. $ln(g)$ is

```
lng<-c(0.037738369, 0.019262104, 0.017573858, 0.010026152, 0.008910295+ 
      +0.007810615, 0.006545131, 0.009890622, 0.003744363)
```

The output of linear model `lm(lng~t)` in R is

```
lm(formula = lng ~ t)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            t  
   0.035476    -0.003139
```

Now, I would expect to simply put `ln(g) = 0.037571 - 0.003477*t`, which means `g = e^(0.037571 - 0.003477*t)` for `t > 11` in order to get the extrapolated values, but it's weird. `lm(g~t)` is giving me better output.

---

I believe that I need to get $a$ and $b$ firstly and then I can predict values. The result is `a=-2.390289,b=-0.326016`. I just don't know how to get it.

Comment: Don't know if this will help much, but I don't get those values for $\ln g$ _at all_.  My first few numbers are 0.0377384, 0.0192621, 0.0175739....

Comment: Because in r you use the lm function as lm(thing you want to predict ~ variables)  also if it is a log fit then why not use ln(g)~ intercept + t since r will do the rest for you? Ps I am using a phone hence no formatting ;)

Comment: tabstop: my bad, it's edited now.___ @Chinny84: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Linear regression in log-log coordinates leads to the result shown below :

[image]

Comment: Well, I'm not looking for the best fit of data, i.e. g=exp(a+b*t) has to be used. I know models with bigger oefficient of determination - I just want to know how to get a and b from regression coefficients and plot these data using that particular exponential curve.

Answer (score 0):

When I plot your data after taking the log, I get $ln g = 0.0355-0.0031 t$ as the best fit.  It doesn't look too good.  The chart is from Excel.  Your values for $\ln g$ are not correct.

[image]

Comment: You are right with me having ln g wrong. I have just edited that. However, you have plot linear trend, not the exponential curve. It is necessary to transform intercept and t coefficient into a and b in order to plot that curve, I just don't know how.

Comment: As I had taken the logs, I did a linear fit.  That corresponds to an exponential curve befire the  logs.